# 'Unexpected Section Title' with Sphinx -- is numpy the issue?

Tags: python, numpy, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

When running

```
sphinx-build . html/
```

in my `doc/` directory, I get the following output:

```
$ sphinx-build . html/
Running Sphinx v0.6.4
No builder selected, using default: html
loading pickled environment... done
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index                 
reST markup error:
HIDDEN/PATH/matplotlib_visualization.py:docstring of simulator.extensions.matplotlib_visualization.beta:20: (SEVERE/4) Unexpected section title.
```

This file has `numpy` imports, and after a little research, it seems like the RST markup that sphinx uses has a problem with the way `numpy` is documented. When I take out the numpy import, the html builds fine.

What would be the best way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

The subject is discussed in this thread: 
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sphinx-users/MAFTlX8pAvk/B9hx7MuBVbIJ

Pierre GM says:
"fredrik, 
Looks like you're using thw numpy standard for your documentation. Consider 
then using the numpydoc extensions that Pauli Virtanen implemented: it's 
available here: <del>http://sphinx.googlecode.com/svn/contrib/trunk/</del> "

Current information abut numpydoc: 
<del>https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt</del>

Moved information about NumpyDoc: https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#docstring-standard