# sphinx severe: unexpected section title -- arbitrary headings in function docstring

Tags: javascript, python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

Using [`autodoc`](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html) and similar tools allows one to compile documentation from source **docstrings**. It doesn't however, seem to allow arbitrary ReST section titles in function or class docstrings, and produces the error:

`SEVERE: Unexpected section title.`

I encoutered a similar problem when trying to document following the numpy style guidelines without `numpydoc`: [unexpected section title with sphinx is numpy the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101281/unexpected-section-title-with-sphinx-is-numpy-the-issue) and
[how does numpy process docstrings into sphinx documentation for parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397483/how-does-numpy-process-docstrings-into-sphinx-documentation-for-parameters)

Here however, I'm actually documenting JavaScript and would simply like to have arbitrary section titles and ReST in a **docstring**.

Javascript docstring api: [sphinx jsapidoc](https://github.com/Nuulogic/sphinx-jsapidoc)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the requirement to add arbitrary section titles and ReST within a docstring can pose challenges; [sphinx-jsapidoc](https://github.com/Nuulogic/sphinx-jsapidoc) is effective for this requirement.